# Pivot data from rows to columns with a particular structure in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data:

```
    var_1   var_2   var_3
0     5.0     7.0     3.0
1     4.0     5.0    10.0
2     4.0     9.0     7.0
3     9.0    10.0     4.0
4     4.0     9.0     3.0
```

the output should be:

```
     var_3   var_4   var_5   var_7   var_9   var_10
0       3       0       1       2       0        0
1       0       1       2       0       0        3
2       0       1       0       3       2        0
3       0       3       0       0       1        2
4       3       1       0       0       2        0
```

It's not a typical pivot, and though It could be done using something like `iterrows` I feel there should be a nicer approach.

What's happened is the values from the rows are used for columns, and the column suffixes are used for the cell values.

## Edit

The question has exactly the information required to answer it - closing it makes zero sense to me so some explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I vote for reopen, because it was wrongly closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get new columns names by `rename` for values after `_`, unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), add `value` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last some data columns cleaning:

```
f = lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1])
df = (df.rename(columns=f)
        .melt(ignore_index=False)
        .set_index('value', append=True)['variable']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename(columns=int)
        .add_prefix('var_')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   var_3  var_4  var_5  var_7  var_9  var_10
0      3      0      1      2      0       0
1      0      1      2      0      0       3
2      0      1      0      3      2       0
3      0      3      0      0      1       2
4      3      1      0      0      2       0
```